# GitForWindows keeps asking for OpenSSH password (Wish Application)

Tags: windows, git, bash, openssh

I just installed GitForWindows and it keeps asking me for a password even if I enter it correctly. I've never seen this dialog pop up before on installations on other machines (though I haven't used Git Bash until now).

[image]

How can I prevent this from popping up? I'm using `ssh-agent` manually anyway.

Comment: It seems as if ssh.exe is asking the password for the git@... user and not for any ssh key. Is your key loaded in ssh agent?

Comment: @MrTux It was not at the time I posted the question, but it is now and the dialog still opens from time to time. Also there is no action that could explicitly trigger this dialog pop up as far as I can see, it just randomly appears from time to time and I have to click "Cancel" multiple times because it re-opens a few times before it's quiet again.

Comment: any luck on it?

Comment: Some problem for me. Only on some repositories thou. It is very annoying. If anyone knows a solution, please don't keep it a secret.

Comment: thanks for the information, I was canceling access with Ctrl + C because I thought the windows would never stop, at least now I know that if I cancel several times it works haha